# AngularJS: testing a service with a persistent rootscope

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js

I want to test my AngularJS alert service like this (using Mocha and Chai):

```
describe('service', function() {
    var alertService;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('components.services'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_alertService_, _$rootScope_) {
        alertService = _alertService_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    describe('alertService', function() {
        it('should start with zero alerts', function() {
            $rootScope.should.have.property('alerts').with.length(0);
        });

        it('should add an alert of type danger', function() {
            alertService.add('danger', 'Test Alert!');
            $rootScope.should.have.property('alerts').with.length(1);
        });

        it('should add an alert of type warning', function() {
            alertService.add('warning', 'Test Alert!');
            $rootScope.should.have.property('alerts').with.length(2);
        });

        it('should close via the alert', function() {
            var alert = $rootScope.alerts[0];
            alert.should.have.property('close');
            alert.close();
            $rootScope.should.have.property('alerts').with.length(1);
        });
    });
});
```

However, the beforeEach method is resetting the rootScope before each test (I kinda expected it to run before each "describe", not each "it"), so counting the number of alerts doesn't work.

What's the best way around this? Have multiple asserts within one big "it"? I'm quite new to unit testing in general and in Javascript in particular so any explanation is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

it's resetting the rootScope because you have it declared as a variable and not actually injected into the method...try passing in $rootScope and delete the var declaration of it.

Comment: If I try to inject it on the describe (`describe('alertService', inject(function($rootScope) {`) then I get the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$modules' of null.

Comment: Injecting it on the "it" doesn't seem to work either, still have the original problem where it's reset on every test.

Comment: you don't use the word "inject"...it's (describe('alertService', (function($rootScope) {}

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, $rootScope is then undefined.